# Post on S3 via CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am using a Social Network Script (Sngine), here I have enabled the storage feature of AWS. The AWS Bucket S3 is set up the folder /uploads stored in S3.
Cloudfront I have also set up so that media content is also delivered from cloudfront, so that works fine so far. Unfortunately, the saving doesn't work, so when new posts are made with pictures/videos, or similar
are made, it is not uploaded.
My bucket policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mys3bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::MYAWSID:distribution/MYDISTRIBUTIONID"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipalPut",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mys3bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::MYAWSID:distribution/MYDISTRIBUTIONID"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity MYOAIID"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mys3bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My CloudFront Behaviors:

Allowed HTTP methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

MY Cache key and origin requests:

- Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)
  CachingOptimized
  CORS-S3Origin

Response headers policy: SimpleCORS

Do you have some tips for me that I can save the uploads to the S3 and have them delivered via CloudFront?
Sorry for my bad english, I hope it is still understandable :-)

I have already changed the CloudFront Behaviors so far and also the bucket policies, in these I had not included the following part before:

```
"Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipalPut",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mys3bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::MYAWSID:distribution/MYDISTRIBUTIONID"
                }
            }
```